# What directory is cleaned when 'sudo apt autoclean' is executed?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

If the following sequence of commands is executed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt
```

it shows 92M - of course for this current point of time. It could be other value.

If the following sequence of commands is executed:

```
sudo apt autoclean
sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt
```

it still shows 92M

Finally, if the following sequence of commands is executed:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt
```

it shows 28K - so is clear that `sudo apt clean` cleans the `/var/cache/apt` directory

**Note** for either `sudo apt autoclean` or `sudo apt clean` there is no output/result, but according with some tutorials the target directory used for *cleaning* purposes is `/var/cache/apt`, but ...

**Question:**

- What directory is cleaned when `sudo apt autoclean` is executed?

Comment: Have you read the `man` page?  It says "*Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless. This allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing out of control. The configuration option APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from being erased if it is set to off.*"  ie. its actions are controlled by the package database rather than acting on contents of a directory

Comment: Just in case - that description appears in `man apt-get` but not in `man 8 apt`